# AudioContext doesn't appear to exist in Chrome 35

Tags: google-chrome, web-audio-api

Why has this code started erroring in chrome 35? Not sure when it started but it used to work around November 2013.

```
try {
// Fix up for prefixing
window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext ? new window.AudioContext() :
       window.webkitAudioContext ? new window.webkitAudioContext() :
       window.mozAudioContext ? new window.mozAudioContext() :
       window.oAudioContext ? new window.oAudioContext() :
       window.msAudioContext ? new window.msAudioContext() :
       undefined;
context = new AudioContext();
}
catch(e) {
      console.log('Error');
      console.log(e);
}
```

Edit: To clarify, this turned out to be a badly caught issue with getUserMedia now requiring all three input arguments. I was missing the error function:

```
navigator.getUserMedia (

  // constraints
  {
     video: false,
     audio: true
  },

  // successCallback
  function(localMediaStream) {
     // Do something with the audio here
  },

  // errorCallback
  function(err) {
     console.log("The following error occured: " + err);
  }
);
```

Answer (score 3):

Chrome 35 started supporting AudioContext.

Why are you new()ing the AudioContexts in lines 3-7?

This is better captured, BTW, as:

```
window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
context = new AudioContext();
```

There's no vendor-prefixed version in any browser other than webkitAudioContext.

Comment: I've changed to your code (I assume you mean't || not | ?) and I get the error: "Failed to execute 'webkitGetUserMedia' on 'Navigator': 3 arguments required, but only 2 present."

I am running the OS X Yosemite Beta.. maybe that's causing some issues?

Comment: No, you need to use |, as cwilso said.Also, getUserMedia changed not a long time ago. The third argument is now mandatory (it used to be optional), and is a callback called in case of error.

Comment: It's that third now mandatory argument that caught me off guard. thanks for the pointers